# Can we take the infimum over a variable set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Suppose that we have a family of functions $\lbrace f_{\alpha}(x)\rbrace_{\alpha}$ define on an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, and  $\alpha$ runs over a set $\Gamma$. Assume that the family is uniformly bounded below. Suppose that for each fixed $x$, there exists a nonempty subset $E_{x}$ of $\Gamma$. My question is: can we define a function $g(x)$ as
$$g(x)=\inf_{\alpha\in E_x}f_{\alpha}(x)?$$
I mean, does the fact that $E_{x}$ is not a fixed set pose a problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can (and should) think about $E_x$ as a function from the set of $x$'s to the subsets of $\Gamma$, then $g(x)$ is just a composition of well-defined functions.

First $x\mapsto E_x$, then $E_x\mapsto\{f_\alpha(x)\mid\alpha\in E_x\}$, which is then mapped to its infimum (assuming that $f_\alpha$ is a real-valued function, or in some other domain where $\inf$ is a well-defined function for non-empty sets).

Comment: The problem is that this function does not have the same properties as the infimum over a fixed set. For instance, if $\lbrace f_{\alpha}\rbrace$ are continuous, the function $g(x)$ fails to be lower semi-continuous.

Comment: Life is tough...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I should "check" when the answer given is satisfactory. You answer is very satisfactory. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, you're welcome!